# How to Select all the column name from file (e.g:- csv or, json or, parquet) in Apache Drill

Tags: apache-drill

I am using Drill in Window 10 in embedded mode having latest version 1.8.

I have a **Drill query** for selecting all the columns from a  sql server database table:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT info.COLUMN_NAME AS `NAME`, info.TABLE_SCHEMA AS `TABLESCHEMA`, info.TABLE_NAME AS `TABLENAME`, info.ORDINAL_POSITION AS `POSITION`, info.IS_NULLABLE AS `ISNULLABLE`, info.DATA_TYPE AS `DATATYPE`, tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE AS `CONSTRAINTTYPE`, kcufk.TABLE_SCHEMA AS `REFRENCESCHEMA`, kcufk.TABLE_NAME AS `REFRENCETABLE`, kcufk.COLUMN_NAME AS `REFRENCECOLUMN` FROM DemoSQLServer.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.`COLUMNS` info LEFT OUTER JOIN DemoSQLServer.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.`KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` kcu ON kcu.COLUMN_NAME = info.COLUMN_NAME AND kcu.TABLE_NAME = info.TABLE_NAME LEFT OUTER JOIN DemoSQLServer.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.`TABLE_CONSTRAINTS` tc ON tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME AND tc.TABLE_NAME = kcu.TABLE_NAME LEFT OUTER JOIN DemoSQLServer.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.`REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS` rk ON rk.CONSTRAINT_NAME = tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME LEFT OUTER JOIN DemoSQLServer.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.`KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` kcufk ON kcufk.CONSTRAINT_NAME = rk.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME WHERE info.TABLE_NAME = 'Attribute' AND info.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' ORDER BY info.ORDINAL_POSITION ASC;
```

**This query will return all the columns from the attribute table.**

**I want to select column name from some files(e.g:-csv or, parquet or, json,etc).
Is it possible using Drill.?**

Comment: your question is not clear. Neither you mentioned OS details nor Drill version.

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is here? Are you asking how to run a query like this on a CSV or JSON file?

Comment: improve your formatting -  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Do you want to perform a join query on csv/json/parquet files? Local files or HDFS files?

Comment: @devツ:- Suppose i have one parquet file in my local directory. i want to select some column from that file. Is it possible?

Comment: sanjiv the highlighter  you used it for code blocks not any text lines. Please read the link I shared or google about formatting question on stackoverflow.

Comment: yes you can. check https://drill.apache.org/docs/querying-parquet-files/

Comment: @devツ:- In drill doc they are using `select * ` which will returns all the table data. But Is it possible to to select only `column name`. ?I want to select only  the column name from parquet file.

Answer (score 2):

You can select columns for files in a similar way like tables.

Sample query:

```
select N_NAME,N_REGIONKEY from dfs.`<drill-home>/sample-data/nation.parquet`;
```

*P.S. - Make sure `dfs` plugin is enabled.*